# Couchbase openIDConnect Authentication ios

Tags: ios, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am trying to use couchbase DB and set up authentication for it using Authorization Code flow. I followed the steps in this [link](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.5/guides/authentication/openid/index.html). I prepared ConfigJson accordingly. Using Pods i installed Couchbase lite for ios and gave the authenticator in following way:

```
let url = URL.init(string: "http://my-ip:4984/project_name/_oidc")!
pusher = database.createPushReplication(url)
pusher.continuous = true
let authenticator = CBLAuthenticator.openIDConnect({(loginURL: URL, redirectURL: URL, Nonnull: CBLOIDCLoginContinuation) -> Void in

                    print(loginURL,redirectURL)
                })
                pusher.authenticator = authenticator
                pusher.start()
```

But when I Checked it in terminal "http://my-ip:4984/project_name/_oidc/_session" is hit instead and I am not receiving any callback to the mobile. What am i doing wrong? Sorry I am just a beginner. Why is _session added at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set URL of Your database instead of setting _oidc endpoint. Authentification steps are taken care of by Couchbase Lite's Open ID Connect authenticator.

So, You need to use let `url = URL.init(string: "http://my-ip:4984/project_name/")!`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try this and give you the bounty if it is right